# CORS on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, cors, tomcat6

I'm trying to enable CORS on Tomcat 6.
Has anyone had success doing that in production?

I followed some steps using filters, editing the file web.xml and putting some jars into tomcat library like described in this [link](https://www.dforge.net/2013/09/16/enabling-cors-on-apache-tomcat-6/), but without success.

Any opinion will be appreciated.
Tks in advance.

Comment: Can you put what error you getting on client side?

Comment: Yes, for sure - please, find the logs bellow.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.mysite.com:8080/file.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin www.mysite.com:3000' is therefore not allowed access.** 

1) I've a rest call on www.mysite.com:3000 to my www.mysite.com:8080 that returns a JSON message with the full web path of the file.jpg.
2) All access to that rest call will be made after authentication on www.mysite.com:8080
3) I've a Filter controlling the permissions of some images, including file.jpg on www.mysite.com:8080/Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Did you add the headers properly? Look here : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying filter, for CORS you can try and use the following method.

What you can do is modify the method to :

```
 public Response getYourMethod( HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception, IOException{
  //then your code
 }
```

Now after that add the following:

since the browser looks for `www.mysite.com:3000` in the Allow Origin Header, you need to make sure this is getting added in the following line:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "www.mysite.com:3000");
```

To get the `www.mysite.com:3000` you can use :

```
request.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + request.getRemotePort();
```

But if the browser looks for localhost then go for the :

```
request.getRemoteHost().
```

Avoid adding `*` because some browsers will not still allow that and can be rejected by preflight requests.

If you want to add the filters, then look over [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)

Make sure that you add the headers and methods properly as mentioned in the post.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi - tks for the comments - this is my code right now running on www.mysite.com:8080 - still not working, any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/19kLwc1t/ Tks again.

Comment: @D.Francis Can you change the url like the one I showed in the edited answer

Comment: yes - both ways have failed, this is my filter on web.xml under /catalina-home/conf https://jsfiddle.net/19kLwc1t/1/ 
As I said, I'm using Tomcat 6 with the jars of CORS under catalina-home/lib
Any ideas? Tks again.